# Is there a minimized version of the jQuery element selection library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, element

I want to be able to use jQuery-like element selection syntax to find DOM elements, but I don't want to include the full jQuery code. Is there an already-minimized version of the element selection code that I can get somewhere? I'm looking for a small, simple version to include in a stand-alone library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) library which is used by jQuery internally

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support older browsers (IE7 and friends), just use `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll`. They accept CSS selectors and are used internally by jQuery wherever possible.

Comment: I'll try this out too.